# Cutting down output after bytes to gigabytes conversion

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

I'm converting bytes into gigabytes and when I do, the output is something like:

57.686961286

Is there any way I can cut down the total number displayed to something like:

57.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you could use the [`Math.Round` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx)**, which will round a value to the nearest integer or the specified number of decimal places.

The appropriate overload will be chosen depending on the type of the value that you pass in (either a `Double` or a `Decimal`). Specifying an `Integer` value for the second parameter allows you to indicate the number of fractional digits the result should contain. In this case, you would specify "1".

Of course, the result would not be 57.6. When the value 57.686… is rounded, the 8 in the hundredths place causes the 6 in the tenths place to round *up* to 7, rather than down to 6. The correct result is 57.7.

Certain overloads of the above method also allow you to specify a [rounding style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) to apply when the number in question is halfway between two others, either IEEE Standard 754 section 4 rounding (also called rounding-to-nearest, or "banker's" rounding), or the "away from zero" style that you probably learned in school.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the value for display using the [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) method, which takes a format parameter.

```
double myValue = 57.686961286;
string outputValue = myValue.ToString("0.0"); //output: 57.7, rounded
```